# How to split Node.js files in several files

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app     = express();
var path    = require("path");

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/views/index.html'));
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
}).listen(3000);

console.log("Running at Port 3000");

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.json(200, {'test': 'it works!'})
})
```

I will have many services (like the `test` one), and I don't want to have them all on the same file.

I read in another question in Stack Overflow, that I can require other files like this: `var express = require("./model/services.js");` And in that file write all the services, but it's throwing `app is not defined` when I start Node.

How can I separate codes?

Comment: You can require `express` in a different file named `test.js` and have all the test code inside it. Then just export it and call it later in the main app file.

Comment: But if I required `express` in the other file, how do I get the instance of the app?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can define your routes in different files say *test-routes.js* like this:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
        res.json(200, {'test': 'it works!'})
    })
}
```

Now in your main file say *server.js* you can import your route file like this:

```
var express = require("express");
var app     = express();
var path    = require("path");

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/views/index.html'));
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
}).listen(3000);

console.log("Running at Port 3000");

// import your routes
require('./test-routes.js')(app);
```

Answer (score 4):

your `test.js` should look something like:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  res.json(200, {'test': 'it works!'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

and the `app.js` (assuming other is some other route defined similarly to test.js):

```
var test = require("./routes/test.js");
var other = require("./routes/other.js");
...
//all your code for creating app 
...
app.use('/test', test);
app.use('/other', other);
```

Comment: I still have the same issue in this case, I get the error app does not exists in the test.js