# Node.js Express Server Side Structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to find a solution for my server and for its structure. What I want to do is separate.

```
app.post("/login", function(request, response) {  
});

app.post("/register", function(request, response) {  
});

app.get("/", function(request, response) {  
});
```

into different files. In my case, they are all standing in a file called "server.js". How can I separate them to work on them better?, and run all of them at the same time. I searched out this situation and I found different types of this case. But couldn't get a clear answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include route handlers in multiple files in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059246/how-to-include-route-handlers-in-multiple-files-in-express)

Comment: Possible answer also in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33946972/how-to-split-node-js-files-in-several-files

Comment: I think it will be more beneficial to keep all of your routes in one file, but have those routes call functions in different files. That way you have all your routing in one place, but can separate the business logic functions.

Comment: @jsalonen those answers are a bit dated for modern express routing methodology. Correct, but dated.

Comment: @jsalonen thanks for the topics. They are all old but can be a solution for me.

Comment: @Matthew It's hard to work on it. I need to separate them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing you can do is incorporate a "router" into your express functions.

Here's a small sample of how I do it. (Shameless plug, feel free to view my games source code for a more full detailed router [here](https://github.com/RUJodan/Source-React/blob/master/server.js))

server.js

```
import login from "./routes/login";
app.use("/login", login);
```

login.js

```
const router = express.Router();
router.route("/") //this points to the root route of /login
    .post((req, res) => {
        //post function here
    })
    .get((req, res) => {
        //get function here
    })
```

This allows you do do very specific functional routing, along with splitting the routers into different files (I store them in routes)

```
app_root
----routes
--------login.js
----server.js
```

This is a basic structure of how it will look in your file architecture. Very clean, very easy to modularize.

Comment: This is IMO the best solution. You can look at `server.js`, which is essentially the routing documented in one file, but you can also split up the functions/business logic into logical pieces.

Answer (score 1):

As of the above comment by Sterling Archer, we use similar folder hierarchy for our development as well

```
server.js (node http server)
app/
  | app.js (express app)
  | api/
     | router.js (express master router to handler "/"
     | exampleApi/
          | exampleRouter.js (routes for example api)
```

PS:
We use below yoeman generator to generate above folder structure for us
[yaoeman generator npmjs link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-dodan) ,
[yo-dodan git repo](https://github.com/smaldeniya/generator-dodan/tree/master/app/templates/src)  (to get an idea of file structure)